# Continuously keep passing information from previous Activity to Current

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, message

I want to send or forward the information to the next activity,practical-
I have a Bluetooth Chat On which I receive message but on clicking a button the activity changes,I want to yet keep receiving the messages while on the new Activity
[Bluetooth Chat code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)

Comment: Post the code that you tried along with the issue(s) with it.

Comment: can you be more explicit please? We need more detail, so we can help you

Comment: you cannot do that: there is no guarantee that previous activity is still "alive"

Comment: Code is already present ,the link,I tried merging two activities to one to keep the information,turned out to mess up the code,Any code other than the link is not helpful

Comment: @FranciscoMelicias as stated above the only logical code I can display is the link

Comment: @pskink ,is there a way to keep it "alive" till the necessity's are met?

Comment: yes, by making Bluetooth stuff in `android.app.Service` and binding to that service from different activities

Comment: Works like a doll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you received the  message on on BluetoothChatService, Broadcast the received message using local broadcast , And receive the message on the Activity which you need using Broadcast receiver.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Example on Local broadcast implementation
http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/

Hope it solves your problem .